# Powershell mask password

Tags: powershell, passwords

I would like to prompt user to enter a list of passwords, one line at a time. When the person types the passwords, it should appear as *******

I have a function

```
function Read-MultiLineInputBoxDialogPwd([string]$Message, [string]$WindowTitle, [string]$DefaultText){

    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

    # Create the label
    $label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,10)
    $label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
    $label.AutoSize = $true
    $label.Text = $Message

    # Create the TextBox used to capture the user's text
    $textBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $textBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40)
    $textBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(575,200)     
    $textBox.AcceptsReturn = $true    
    $textBox.AcceptsTab = $false    
    $textBox.Multiline = $true    
    $textBox.ScrollBars = 'Both'    
    $textBox.Text = $DefaultText
    $textBox.UseSystemPasswordChar = $True

    # Create the OK button.     
    $okButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button     
    $okButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(415,250)     
    $okButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,25)     
    $okButton.Text = "OK"    
    $okButton.Add_Click({ $form.Tag = $textBox.Text; $form.Close() }) 

    # Create the Cancel button.     
    $cancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button     
    $cancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(510,250)     
    $cancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,25)     
    $cancelButton.Text = "Cancel"    
    $cancelButton.Add_Click({ $form.Tag = $null; $form.Close() }) 

    # Create the form.     
    $form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form      
    $form.Text = $WindowTitle    
    $form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(610,320)     
    $form.FormBorderStyle = 'FixedSingle'    
    $form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"    
    $form.AutoSizeMode = 'GrowAndShrink'    
    $form.Topmost = $True    
    $form.AcceptButton = $okButton    
    $form.CancelButton = $cancelButton    
    $form.ShowInTaskbar = $true

    # Add all of the controls to the form.     
    $form.Controls.Add($label)     
    $form.Controls.Add($textBox)     
    $form.Controls.Add($okButton)     
    $form.Controls.Add($cancelButton) 

    # Initialize and show the form.     
    $form.Add_Shown({$form.Activate()})     
    $form.ShowDialog() > $null   # Trash the text of the button that was clicked.           

    # Return the text that the user entered.     
    return $form.Tag 
}
```

And I call the function

```
$multiLineTextPwd = Read-MultiLineInputBoxDialogPwd -Message "All possible passwords" -WindowTitle "Passwords" -DefaultText "Please enter all possible passwords, one line at a time..."
```

But when it pops up, the text still appears in plaintext, even though I set the following

```
$textBox.UseSystemPasswordChar = $True
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I honestly feel that this would be better accomplished by having a single-line text box and an 'Add Another Password' button where the user could enter a password, and then click the button to add another password. You would just keep adding them to an array, and would have to make sure that when they submit that it checks for anything in that box and adds anything left to the array before performing actions.

All password masking references when I went and looked at the MSDN listing for the Textbox class all specifically state Single Line Textbox, so it may well be that you can't use masking with a multiline textbox.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.passwordchar%28VS.80%29.aspx) you'll see that for multiline text boxes, the `UseSystemPasswordChar` has no effect.

Comment: Nice find, I didn't look for older versions, I only checked the .Net 4.5 TextBox class.

Answer (score -1):

implement keydown event of mutiline textbox, append * into TB, and append key code string into a string variable.

Comment: Then when the user presses backspace or adds a line in the middle of the string? It gets unmanageable quickly. Pragmatic approach is to change the UI.